# How to visualise attributes from other columns in a histogram in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, histogram

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: "C_code", "F_namn" and "D_namn", containing strings. I want to create a histogram that shows the distribution of the "F_namn" (geographical regions), and within each bin, one can se the distribution of the "C_code", which is a, b or c, being stacked on top of each other.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
C_code = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a']
F_namn = ['sthlm', 'norr', 'syd', 'norr', 'norr', 'sthlm', 'syd', 'norr']
D_namn = ['ff', 'rr', 'ff', 'gg', 'ff', 'rr', 'rr', 'ff']
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'C_code': C_code, 'F_namn': F_namn, 'D_namn': D_namn})
df_counts_test = df_test.apply(pd.value_counts)

df_counts_test['F_namn'].dropna().plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Here is the histogram of F namn, I want each bin to have 3 "regions" containing its distribution of the "C_code" column from the same dataframe.

[image]

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? You could first calculate all values and later plot it as boxes

Comment: BTW: you could add example data (as text) which we could use to create answer. And you could also show expected result for example data - and this can be image. And put it all in question, not in comment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, realized that the question might have been a bit vague. Is it more clear now?

Comment: it is not `histogram` but normal bar-plot. If you check [documentation for bar-plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) then you see example with `bar(stacked=True)` .

Comment: question would be better if you would put some example data directly in code (instead of load from file) - so we could simply copy and run it.

Comment: Okay, now you should be able to run it. I still don't understand how to stack other attributes from the dataframe

Comment: you should run only one plot - without `['F_namn']` - `df_counts_test.plot.bar(stacked=True)` - but problem is that your calculations are useless for this plot. You should use `groupby('F_namn')` and then count values `C_code` for every group. Using `value_counts` you count all values - not for every `F_namn` separatelly. If you use `print()` to see what you have in `df_counts_test` then you will see that you don't have values which you want to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you have wrong calculations.
If you use `print(df_counts_test)` then you should see that results are useless for plot which you want.

Using `pd.value_counts` you calculate total counts. And your plot shows only how many times you have names `sthlm`, `norr`, `syd` on list but it doesn't count how many times you get `a`,`b`,`c` for every `sthlm`, `norr`, `syd`.

You should rather use `groupby('F_namn')` and in every group you should use `value_counts` on column `'C_code'` to calculate for every group separatelly.

---

First I create `DataFrame` for results - and I will add columns with results for every group.
It needs rows/indexes at start. If I don't define `index` then it will not add results.

```
result = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Next I group by `F_name` and calculate `value_counts` for every group separatelly

```
for name, data in df_test.groupby('F_namn'):
    #print(name)
    #print(data['C_code'].value_counts())
    result[name] = data['C_code'].value_counts()
```

And this gives me:

```
   norr  sthlm  syd
a   3.0    2.0  NaN
b   NaN    NaN  2.0
c   1.0    NaN  NaN
```

I could replace `NaN` with zero but it should plot correctly even with `NaN`

```
result = result.fillna(0)
```

It needs also to `transpose` it - it means convert columns into rows.

```
result = result.T  # transpose
```

and this gives me:

```
         a    b    c
norr   3.0  0.0  1.0
sthlm  2.0  0.0  0.0
syd    0.0  2.0  0.0
```

And finally I can plot it

```
result.plot.bar(stacked=True)

plt.show()
```

and this gives me

[image]

---

Full working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C_code = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a']
F_namn = ['sthlm', 'norr', 'syd', 'norr', 'norr', 'sthlm', 'syd', 'norr']
D_namn = ['ff', 'rr', 'ff', 'gg', 'ff', 'rr', 'rr', 'ff']

df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    'C_code': C_code,
    'F_namn': F_namn,
    'D_namn': D_namn
})

print(df_test)

result = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

for name, data in df_test.groupby('F_namn'):
    #print(name)
    #print(data['C_code'].value_counts())
    result[name] = data['C_code'].value_counts()

print(result)
    
result = result.fillna(0)  # put `zero` 
result = result.T  # transpose

print(result)

result.plot.bar(stacked=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was what I was looking for!